# How to construct Poisson process as a random variable in order to evaluate integrals?

Tags: probability-theory, random-variables, poisson-distribution

I want to find a probability space $\Omega$ that represents Poisson process as
$$\Pi : \Omega \to \{A \in \mathcal{P}{(\mathbb{R^+})}\mid |A| = \aleph_0\}$$
Which is a  mapping from $\Omega$ to all countable subsets of the set of non-negative real numbers.

To put it in words, once a state of world $\omega \in \Omega$ is obtained, all the points of arrival on time line is determined.

How can I construct this probability space $(\Omega, \mathcal{B},\mu)$

The purpose of this construction is that I want to evaluate integrals taking the form as
$$\int_{\Omega}\sum_{x \in \Pi(\omega)}f(x)d\mu$$
in which $f(x)$ can be interpreted as a payoff incurred at time $x$.
Or more generally, integrals like
$$\int_{\Omega}g(\sum_{x \in \Pi(\omega)}f(x))d\mu$$

Comment: A canonical approach is to order the points of the process as $0<T_1<T_2<\ldots$, using the equivalence $A=\{T_n\mid n\geqslant1\}$, then one is reduced to build a sequence $(T_n)$ with prescribed joint distribution, and for that, everything works. (It seems like putting your hands on an introductory text to Poisson point processes would really help.)

Comment: "This question has not received enough attention." Really? What about reacting to the comment above?

Comment: @Did: Sorry for delay of reply. I did as you suggested, taking the only book titled Poisson Processes by J.F:C Kingman in the library, in the hope that I can understand your point and find an explict construction of $\Omega$.  But I  couldn't.

Comment: Are you unable to build an i.i.d. sequence (Tn) with prescribed distribution? Then **this** should be your question!

Comment: @Did, Thank you! I think I understand your point now. But what does "equivalence" mean in your first comment?

Comment: @Did So it's $Prob(\sum_{i \in \mathbb{N}\cap[1,n]}T_i \leq t) = \int_0^t \frac{\lambda^{n+1}x^ne^{-\lambda x}}{n!} dt$ , right?

Comment: But I still find it difficult to calculate the last expectation in the question. For example, at time $\sum_{i=1}^n T_i$, a unit payoff arrives, it is discounted by $e^{-r(\sum_{i=1}^n T_i)}$, my utility is $\frac{c^{1-\rho}-1}{1-\rho}$, in which $c$ is the sum of the discounted payoffs. How can I calculate this:

$$\mathbb{E} \frac{(\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}e^{-r(\sum_{i=1}^n T_i)})^{1-\rho}-1}{1-\rho}$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One can use product probability space to model a Poisson process. Let $$\Omega = \prod_{k = 1}^\infty \mathbb{R}^+, \mathcal{F} = \sigma\left(\prod_{k=1}^\infty\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}^+)\right)\text{ and }\mu = \prod_{k=1}^\infty \mathrm{Poisson}(\mathbb{R}^+),$$ where $\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}^+)$ is the Borel $\sigma$-algebra on $\mathbb{R}^+$ and $\mathrm{Poisson}(\mathbb{R}^+)$ is the Lebesgue–Stieltjes measure on $\mathbb{R}^+$ such that $\mathrm{Poisson}([0,x])=1-e^{-\lambda x}$ for all $x \ge 0$.

Now define $\Pi\colon \Omega \to \mathcal{P}_{\aleph_0}(\mathbb{R}^+)$ by $$\Pi(\omega) = \Pi(\omega_1, \omega_2, \dots) = \{t : t = \omega_1 + \dots + \omega_n, n\in \mathbb{N}\}.$$